# Issue with connections pool on mysql

Tags: mysql, api, go

I'm having some issues with the api I'm developing: sometimes (yes, not always) when I make a request to the golang server from my angular app, it gaves me this error: "sql: database is closed" when I'm tring to execute "QueryContext", but I figured that it happens more frequently on a func that request a larger data from database (200 record top).

Is there a way to check if the connection is still open\valid? shouldn't golang's connection pool do it automatically? (I have other api more "light" in the same server with the same database and everything work smootly)

Is there any MySql setting I should change?(mysql has defaullt settings)

golang version: 1.16,
Mysql 8.0.17

Hre is an example of my code:
on package database.go

```
func OpenConnection() (*sql.DB, error)
{
    connection, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root@/my_database")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error opening the connection with the database")
        return nil, err
    }
    return connection, nil
}
```

On main.go

```
func main() {
    ---
    http.HandleFunc("/apicall1", customFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/apicall2", customFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/apicall3", customFunc)
}
func customFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := database.OpenConnection()
    if err != nil {
        //handle error 500 response
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    switch(r.URL.Path) {
    case "url1": my_package.Func1(conn)
    case "url2": my_package.Func2(conn)
    case "url3": my_package.Func3(conn)
    ...
    default: //handle not found response
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your Go code?

Comment: Matteo you are opening too many connections. Your app should generally open only a single `*sql.DB` and use that throughout the lifetime of the app. i.e. Calling OpenConnection in every handler for every request is **bad**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787804/does-db-close-need-to-be-called/50788205#50788205

Comment: The documentation on [`sql.Open`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.6#Open) says:  *"The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. **Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB**."*

Comment: But! You MUST `Close` every returned `*sql.Rows`. You MUST `Scan` every returned `*sql.Row`. You MUST `Commit` or `Rollback` every `*sql.Tx`. And you MUST `Close` every `*sql.Stmt` that you aren't going to use anymore.

Comment: Ok, so i must move the opening in the main func before http.HandleFunc. For the *sql.Rows and everithing else I'm quite sure to close it, but I will check

Comment: thanks!! sorry but I'm still learning golang, write it as a response and will sign it a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your sql.DB for better performance from your pool and to avoid hitting max limit of your db allowed connection, here as an example I have made max 100 connection and idle 25 you can change it as per the load. Also it's a nice idea to ping db after making successful connection, just to ensure connection is success.

```
func OpenConnection() (*sql.DB, error)
{
    connection, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root@/my_database")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error opening the connection with the database")
        return nil, err
    }
    connection.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(25)
    connection.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(100)
    dberr = connection.DB().Ping()
    if dberr != nil {
        log.Println("failed to ping db repository : %s", dberr)
        return nil, dberr
    }
    return connection, nil
}
```

Reference - https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/configuring-sqldb